White bar appears while navigating through pages on a WPF
I'm a student trying to figure out how WPF works. I'm navigating to another page after pressing a button but for some reason there is a white bar at the bottom of the screen when I load said page. This does not happen if I directly load this on the Main Window. How could I get rid of that?
I tried some things like changing the image or resizing the page but none of this worked.
MainWindow.xaml:
<Window x:Class="PokemonGroveGreen.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PokemonGroveGreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Pokémon GroveGreen" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="menu" Content="Battle"  Click="ChangePage" Margin="349,191,349,191"/>
        <StackPanel>
            <Frame x:Name="mainMenu" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Frame>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

private void ChangePage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mainMenu.NavigationService.Navigate(new MainMenu());
}

Page:
<Page x:Class="PokemonGroveGreen.MainMenu"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PokemonGroveGreen"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="MainMenu">

    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="/Images/BattleScene.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Page>

screenshot with weird line

screenshot without the line if i put the image on MainWindow


Please post you xaml code and screenshots

What is the purpose of the Viewbox?

I have more elements on my project but i deleted them to not put 200 lines of code on the question. I forgot to get rid of that too

The problem is the StackPanel in MainWindow. A StackPanel only resizes its child elements in one direction.
Replace it by a Grid or some other appropriate Panel:
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="menu" Content="Battle"
            Click="ChangePage" Margin="349,191,349,191"/>

    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="mainMenu" 
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

Or remove it entirely
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="menu" Content="Battle"
            Click="ChangePage" Margin="349,191,349,191"/>

    <Frame x:Name="mainMenu" 
           NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>


That did solve the problem, thank you! A classmate told me how to navigate between pages and he said that I needed to use a StackPanel, which is why it was there. He was having the same problem as me so I will tell him this tomorrow!

You may want to start reading here: Panels Overview.

The image is not the exact size of the Viewbox. You need to change the Stretch property to reflect how you want the image to look. You nee to set it to Fill if you want to strech the image or to UniformToFill if you want to crop it.



Enum





Fill   1
The content is resized to fill the destination dimensions. The aspect ratio is not preserved.


None   0
The content preserves its original size.


Uniform    2
The content is resized to fit in the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio.


UniformToFill  3
The content is resized to fill the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio. If the aspect ratio of the destination rectangle differs from the source, the source content is clipped to fit in the destination dimensions.




the Viewbox is filling the entire page but the image is not

The value of the Stretch property of an Image in a Viewbox has no effect at all. You can set whatever you want, the Image will always fill the Viewbox according to the Stretch property of the Viewbox.
